# Solve our disagreement? relative validity/predictive validity and sample size

Tags: correlation, prediction

The situation: Two groups each with 16 different participants perform 6 tasks. Each group performs the tasks in a different environment. Resulting data is mean performance for each group on each of the 6 tasks. So 6 means for group 1 and 6 means for group 2.  Want to know how well the mean performance of 1st group on each of those 6 tasks, predicts the mean performance of the second group on each of those 6 tasks.

Trying to settle a disagreement here. One side thinks a simple correlation of the 2 sets of 6 means does the trick. Other side things it can't be this simple or can't be done with only 6 means in each group. Also worried that all correlations  appear suspiciously high. But doesn't know the technical arguments are.

Is there an better method? What is the minimum number of observations required.

Any help in dealing with this is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

To obtain a meaningful correlation, the minimum number of pairs of means would be three.  Many would prefer, though, to take into account not just the means, but the degree of variation around the means.  To do this one could take advantage of

- repeated measures ANOVA or MANOVA
- hierarchical linear modeling, a.k.a. multi-level modeling
- generalizability theory.

Such methods would enable one to attribute different amounts of score variation to the type of task, the person, and the group (or the environment, with which group is confounded).